# API to gather list of top token holders

Tags: ether, explorer-api

I working on a Ethereum project and I would like to gather a list of top X (20 for example) Ethereum accounts. This would behave similar to etherscan.io (https://etherscan.io/accounts)

Is there an API that does this ? If not does anyone know of a way to accomplish this. Im curious how etherscan accomplished this. I looked at their and there is no endpoint that behaves like it.

I would like to do this for other ERC20 tokens as well.

Comment: Second code is working, but it allows to parse only 1000 addresses for 1 token. What if I want to parse top 1000 adresses for all tokens? How the script should look like if I have a csv file with number of all smart contracts for let s say 100 tokens. Is it possible to get 100 000 addresses then, so that script changes address in the link? As I understand there should be insertion into string of address like this:
https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/string_formatting.html Variable should be taken from the file, put in the string and new cycle should be started until all variables are put

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/36034)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/36034)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know of any APIs that will achieve what you want.

> If not does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Here's some fairly dumb Python code that scrapes that page and writes it to a `.csv` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

URL = "https://etherscan.io/accounts"
resp = requests.get(URL)
sess = requests.Session()
soup = BeautifulSoup(sess.get(URL).text, 'html.parser')

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(map(str, "Rank Address Balance Percentage TxCount".split()))

    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        rows = [0] * len(tds)
        for i in xrange(len(tds)):
            rows[i] = tds[i].get_text()

        try:
            wr.writerow(rows)
        except:
            # The page contains another table that we're
            # not worried about but which contains special 
            # characters...
            pass
```

> Im curious how etherscan accomplished this.

Probably by parsing the state data and creating their own internal representation of it. This would then allow them to manipulate and present it in any way they like.

> I would like to do this for other ERC20 tokens as well.

Here's a slightly more complicated script (that I wrote a while ago) that lists *all* addresses and balances - in rank order - associated with a given token contract, across multiple Etherscan pages. You can poke around with it to suit your needs. (There's an example contract address currently hard-coded into it.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time

RESULTS = "results.csv"
URL = "https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokenholders2?a=0x6425c6be902d692ae2db752b3c268afadb099d3b&s=0&p="

def getData(sess, page):
    url = URL + page
    print("Retrieving page", page)
    return BeautifulSoup(sess.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

def getPage(sess, page):
    table = getData(sess, str(int(page))).find('table')
    try:
        data = [[X.text.strip() for X in row.find_all('td')] for row in table.find_all('tr')]
    except:
        data = None
    finally:
        return data

def main():
    resp = requests.get(URL)
    sess = requests.Session()

    with open(RESULTS, 'wb') as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        wr.writerow(map(str, "Rank Address Quantity Percentage".split()))
        page = 0
        while True:
            page += 1
            data = getPage(sess, page)

            if data == None:
                break
            else:
                for row in data:
                    wr.writerow(row)
                time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: First script works ok, but only gets data from 1st page, 2nd script seems to be able to change pages, but it doesn't work at all (empty csv). The third script (ethereum.py) doesn't write a

Comment: I am genuinely interested in how you found the url "https://etherscan.io/token/generic-tokenholders2?a=0x6425c6be902d692ae2db752b3c268afadb099d3b&s=0&p=" ? this is a gem

Answer (score 11):

## Intro

I will first explain the steps that you need to do to get the list of token holders. This applies to any language so you can recreate this on your own if you don't use Python. Then I will present my opinionated solution in Python that connects to Infura and explain how it works.

My approach gets you the exact same result as Etherescan's token holders page.

## Steps

To get the list of token holders, you will do:

#### 1. Get all the `Transfer` events from your contract.

For that you need your contract address. Go to [Etherscan Tokens](https://etherscan.io/tokens) page and search for your token, mine was [this one](https://etherscan.io/token/0x83e2be8d114f9661221384b3a50d24b96a5653f5) so my address is `0x83e2be8d114f9661221384b3a50d24b96a5653f5`.

A short lesson in Ethereum: every ERC20 compatible token *should* emit a `Transmit` event (also called a log) whenever this token is sent from one address to another ([example](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/BasicToken.sol#L37)).

You can search for all the `Transmit` events through the JSON RPC interface of any Ethereum node that you have access to. Since I don't currently run an Ethereum node, I connected to a node from [Infura](https://infura.io/). You search for logs by using the [`eth_getlogs`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getlogs) RPC function.

When you search for logs, you don't want all the logs, you only want the `Transmit` logs. The magic string here is `0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef` so you filter all the logs by this *topic*. Why exactly this string is a bit out of scope for this, but you can read more about events and topics [here in the Solidity Docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/abi-spec.html?highlight=topic#events) and in [this tutorial](https://codeburst.io/deep-dive-into-ethereum-logs-a8d2047c7371) that shows how this magic string is done.

To speed up searching it's best if you limit your search to blocks that happened when the contract was deployed or later. For me that was block `5857657`, which translates to hex `0x596179`.

Finally, I can call the RPC method `eth_getLogs` on Infura using the parameters contract `address`, `fromBlock` and `topics`.

#### 2. Parse the events

Ethereum's logs are not straightforward so we need to parse them. If you check one log, there is information about the from address, to address and the token amount, but it's all encoded so you need to know where to look. Check this log entry for example:

```
{'address': '0x83e2be8d114f9661221384b3a50d24b96a5653f5',
 'blockHash': '0x2b25a69098c037c0a49b43697f8dbf2eede8ce4dabdf8585530cad952a521cb3',
 'blockNumber': '0x5a193b',
 'data': '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023934c5a09da1900000',
 'logIndex': '0x52',
 'removed': False,
 'topics': ['0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
            '0x000000000000000000000000c1678c7d5f4d01d30ad72bc5848bb7dfb248b5b9',
            '0x000000000000000000000000b8ca929e2bd96548cabcabc56cfc9a5147cef0ff'],
 'transactionHash': '0x9c85f209b321369f15da6ffef9d0bedeffaab18d7063901197b8f89ffdbe3813',
 'transactionIndex': '0x33'}
```

The from address is the second topic and the to address is the third topic. The amount of tokens transferred is in `data`. Again, you'll have to refer to how Ethereum handles topics and data to understand why this is and how it relates to the `Transmit` event.

You parse it like this:
* Hex decode the `data` to get the amount of tokens transferred. Note that you'll have to move the decimal point by the `decimals` of the token, in my case 18.
* To get the from and to addresses just take the last 40 characters of a topic and prepend it with `0x`.

#### 3. Compute balances

Make a list of all the addresses found in these events and process all the events by adding the token amount to the `to` address and subtracting it from the `from` address. At last just throw out all the addresses with a zero balance.

## Python solution

My Python solution is [here](https://gist.github.com/rokcarl/96a06ab1faf9dfdb0f946aec72ab5ce8). A few comments:

- I'm using the `requests` library to call the JSON RPC on Infura.
- I'm using `Decimal` because it's better than `float` for financial computation.
- I call it like this:

  `from ethereum import *
  contract = "0x83e2be8d114f9661221384b3a50d24b96a5653f5"
  transfers = get_contract_transfers(contract, from_block="0x596179")
  balances = get_balances_list(transfers)`

Comment: This is really interesting. I did not know of Infura before this post. I can't wait to play with this solution this weekend! Thank you. Once I dive in I'll probably have a lot of questions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Try Bitquery's [Token holder API](https://docs.bitquery.io/docs/examples/token-holders/token-holder-api/) can provide details of token holders such as holder count, individual holder, holder with specific balance, and holders on specific blocks or dates.

It also has things like holders created last day.

Additionally, it has the Gini coefficient, Nakamoto index, and Theil index

Open their [Graphql IDE](https://ide.bitquery.io/?endpoint=https://streaming.bitquery.io/graphql)

And run the following API

```
{
  EVM(dataset: archive, network: eth) {
    TokenHolders(
      date: "2023-10-21"
      tokenSmartContract: "0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7"
      where: {Balance: {Amount: {gt: "0"}}}
    ) {
      uniq(of: Holder_Address)
    }
  }
}
```

You can get each and every token holder of any token on Ethereum, Binance, Arbitrum and other chains.

Answer (score 1):

[Ethplorer.io](https://ethplorer.io) provide API call for token holders. But it's limited for top 1000 holders only.

https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/Ethplorer-API#get-top-token-holders