# Get contract address and total holders from a hash transaction

Tags: transactions, erc-20, web3.py, explorer-api

I would like to know if it is possible just from a transaction hash (like this one: '0x98daf5eb1fe55d9ebed51b1ee0b7dcb3bfe04ea5bb0663d40927a683771cdc09')
to be able to retrieve the contract address of the exchanged or transferred token and also know the total number of people who own this token and if the transferred token is a erc-20 token. Is it possible by using the web3.py library or a free API to answer this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you interact with a contract, then the contract address will be in the `to` section of the hash data.

To retrieve Holders information, see here

[API to gather list of top token holders](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41684/api-to-gather-list-of-top-token-holders)